# How exactly does TACACS+ encryption work?

Tags: encryption, authentication, tacacs

I'm trying to understand how TACACS+ encryption works. I've read the [Cisco's TACACS+ RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-grant-tacacs-02) but it's too technical and not very easy to understand. My questions are:

1. Does the TACACS+ device (client) authenticate itself to the server before sending any requests? Is it using any challenge-response technique and which algorithms are used to encrypt the challenge/response packets?
2. What happens when a user is trying to log on to a device using TACACS+? How are the requests sent? Is the whole packet including username + password encrypted and which encryption algorithm is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TACACS+ requires that a pre-shared key (length of the key is restricted to 63 characters) is configured. This is how the device authenticates to the server. This is not 'challenge-response'.

This pre-shared key is used to set up encryption that encrypts the whole packet, which means that usernames and passwords are protected from the start.

How it is encrypted is explained [in the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-grant-tacacs-02) in the section "Body Encryption". It's a version of the One Time Pad.

> In this case, the packet body is encrypted by XOR-ing it byte-wise
> with a pseudo random pad.
>
> ENCRYPTED {data} == data ^ pseudo_pad
>
> The pad is generated by concatenating a series of MD5 hashes (each
> 16    bytes long) and truncating it to the length of the input data.
>
> Whenever used in this document, MD5 refers to the "RSA Data
> Security,    Inc. MD5 Message-Digest Algorithm" as specified in [3].
>
> pseudo_pad = {MD5_1 [,MD5_2 [ ... ,MD5_n]]} truncated to len(data)
>
> The first MD5 hash is generated by concatenating the session_id,
> the    secret key, the version number and the sequence number and then
> run-    ning MD5 over that stream. All of those input values are
> available in    the packet header, except for the secret key which is
> a shared secret    between the TACACS+ client and daemon.
>
> The version number is the one byte combination of the major and
> minor    version numbers.
>
> The session id is used in the byte order in which it appears in the
> TACACS+ header. (i.e. in network byte order, not host byte order).
>
> Subsequent hashes are generated by using the same input stream, but
> concatenating the previous hash value at the end of the input stream.
>
> MD5_1 = MD5{session_id, key, version, seq_no}
>
> MD5_2 = MD5{session_id, key, version, seq_no, MD5_1}
>
> ....
>
> MD5_n = MD5{session_id, key, version, seq_no, MD5_n-1}

User authentication process is described here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/CLIConfigurationGuide/sec_tacacsplus.html

---

Update 01.03.2018:

It seems that Cisco has updated TACACS+ and users are now able to [encrypt passwords with AES128](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/6-x/security/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Security_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01110.html) when using newer high performance switches. So far this only encrypts passwords. It does **not change the encryption of the payload of the TACACS+ protocol**. But it's something. Note though that not all products can make use of this.